# Async FTP uploading

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ftp, async-await

How can I make this code below async, I've no idea how async works with FTP uploading. I tried a lot of things but I don't know where to put 'await' if you upload files.

```
public static async void SelectRectangle(Point SourcePoint, Point DestinationPoint, Rectangle SelectionRectangle, string FilePath)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {

            g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.ftphost + Properties.Settings.Default.ftppath + FilePath + "." + Properties.Settings.Default.extension_plain);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.ftpuser, Properties.Settings.Default.ftppassword);
            request.UseBinary = true;

            bitmap.Save(request.GetRequestStream(), ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

Joery.

Comment: Unless the calling method is marked as async (and as a consequence, the (async) callstack is async all the way down), you can't use async/await.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make the method `async` and then use `await` for any asynchronous operations. You only appear to have one of these, so the following should work:

```
public static async Task SelectRectangle(Point SourcePoint, Point DestinationPoint, Rectangle SelectionRectangle, string FilePath)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {

            g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.ftphost + Properties.Settings.Default.ftppath + FilePath + "." + Properties.Settings.Default.extension_plain);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.ftpuser, Properties.Settings.Default.ftppassword);
            request.UseBinary = true;

            Stream rs = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            bitmap.Save(rs, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot await 'System.IO.Stream' C:\Users\joery\Desktop\LS\ScreenShot.cs 133 33 LiteScreenShot

Comment: @Joery - Sorry, it should be `GetRequestStreamAsync`, see update.